# How to get the host from a URL in pure kotlin Common module

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I need to know how to get the host from URL in "pure" Kotlin. It can be through a library but it can't be JVM. That is because, I am writing a Kotlin Multiplatform library completely in Common module that only depends on Ktor. So that I can support every target Ktor does. And using JVM solution means that I would need to support a solution for every target that I offer.

I was trying to get it through Ktor but didn't find a way yet. So that would also be acceptable solution.

Comment: `io.ktor.http.Url(urlString = "...").host`?

Comment: That worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ktor has it's own `Url` class, and it has all the necessary fields including `host`.

```
io.ktor.http.Url(urlString = "...").host
```